# Image watermark with upload image?

Tags: php, image, upload, image-uploading, watermark

I am use image watermark php script, I have got reference from https://www.sanwebe.com/2014/08/watermark-an-uploaded-image-with-php here.

Issue is that:

```
imagecopy($new_canvas, $watermark, $watermark_left, $watermark_bottom, 0, 0, 300, 100);
```

This is adding successfully water mark to image and when I use:

```
//output image direcly on the browser.
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($new_canvas, NULL , 90);
```

It print image with watermark, but I am not able to upload image with watermark, I use:

```
move_uploaded_file( $temp_name, $destination_path );
```

Uploaded image success but without watermark and

```
move_uploaded_file( $new_canvas, $destination_path );
```

It give error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given.

Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Uh, `$new_canvas` should be a string.

Comment: No it is resource id.

Comment: @JayDeepNimavat Yes, and it should be a string. A filename to be more specific.

Comment: `$new_canvas` is defined where/how exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "imagejpeg" you can output image to browser or file. To save the image in a file try this:

```
imagejpeg($new_canvas, $destination_path , 90);
```